# How to classify new training example after model training in apache spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Reading the src of https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-ann.html :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// Load training data
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt").toDF()
// Split the data into train and test
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 1234L)
val train = splits(0)
val test = splits(1)
// specify layers for the neural network: 
// input layer of size 4 (features), two intermediate of size 5 and 4 and output of size 3 (classes)
val layers = Array[Int](4, 5, 4, 3)
// create the trainer and set its parameters
val trainer = new MultilayerPerceptronClassifier()
  .setLayers(layers)
  .setBlockSize(128)
  .setSeed(1234L)
  .setMaxIter(100)
// train the model
val model = trainer.fit(train)
// compute precision on the test set
val result = model.transform(test)
val predictionAndLabels = result.select("prediction", "label")
val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
  .setMetricName("precision")
println("Precision:" + evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndLabels))
```

Once the model has been trained how can a new training example be classified ?

Can a new training example be added to the `model` where the label is not set and the classifier will try to classify this training example based on the training data ?

Why is it required that the dataframe labels are of type Double ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the only way to add another observation to the model is by incorporating that data point into the training data, in this case to your `train` variable. In order to achieve this, you can convert that point into a `DataFrame` (obviously of only one record) and then use the `unionAll` method. Nevertheless, you will have to retrain the model using this new dataset.

However, to classify observations using your model you will have to convert your unclassified data into a `DataFrame` with the same structure that had your training data. And then use the method `transform` of your model. By the way, notice that models have that method, because they are subclasses of `Transformer`.

Finally, you have to use `Double` because that is the way how the [LabeledPoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint) class was defined. It receives a `Double` as label and a `SparseVector` or `DenseVector` as features. I don't know the exact motivation but in my own experience, which isn't wide, all **classification** and **regression** algorithms work with float point numbers.Furthermore, **gradient descent algorithm**, which is widely used to fit most models, uses numbers not letters nor classes to compute the error in each iteration.

Comment: thanks, please feel free to disagree with any of my comments on your answer. We should not have to re-train each time a new dataframe is added, as the new dataframe is not classified (it does not contain a label) what is the point of re-training. "gradient descent algorithm, which is widely used to fit most models, uses numbers not letters nor classes to compute the error in each iteration" this is not correct as numbers it uses are based on the features , not the labels.

Comment: @blue-sky I said, add another observation (however I will specify it as a complete observation), your question was a bit confounding in this subject that is why I talked about creating another DF to retrain the model. In the last point it used both, the model uses features to compute a label in the case of 2 classes (0.0 - 1.0), which is normally calculated using the sigmonoid function.

Comment: this line : 'val result = model.transform(test)' the labels in the 'test' data are meaningless ? as the 'prediction' column extracted using val predictionAndLabels = result.select("prediction", "label") contains the label and "prediction" is the predicted label ?

Comment: They are, because it adds another column `prediction`. Notice that you even evaluate the model comparing columns `prediction` and `label`. Nevertheless, it is ignored for the compute, because the objective is to evaluate the performance of your model, not to retrain the model as well.

Comment: the dataframe label is the actual value whereas prediction is the predicted value, if the model is working well the prediction will match the label for each dataframe row?

Comment: @blue-sky that's correct, the better the model the less errors you get.

Comment: another method of describing "less errors" : the better the model the closer the prediction value will be to the label value ?

Comment: Depend, on what you want. If you are evaluating a regression model you can use `MAE`, `RMSE`, `MSE`, `R2` as evaluators, due they predict continuous "labels". On the other hand the only way I know to evaluate classification models is by calculating the accuracy, which means determining the number of "failed" predictions `acc = (total - failed) / total`, the better the model the closer to `1.0` the accuracy is.